# Instanciar classe com Injeção de Dependência usando Kotlin em testes unitários

Tags: kotlin, testes-de-unidade, junit, mockito

Estou tentando encontrar uma solução de como posso instanciar uma classe que usa injeção de dependência em testes unitários usando Kotlin e JUnit.

Tenho uma classe que usa injeção de dependência:

```
class MinhaClasse @Inject constructor(val meuService: IMeuService, val outroService: IOutroService, val minhaFactory: IMinhaFactory): IMinhaClasse {
    ...
}
```

Onde no meu construtor primário estou injetando as interfaces de onde vou precisar.

Tenho meu arquivo de testes para essa classe:

```
class MeuServiceTest {
    private val meuService = mock(meuService::class.java)

    @Test
    fun meuMetodoTest() {
        val expectedResult = ...
        ...
        val result = runBlocking { meuService.meuMetodo(parametroDoMetodo) }
        assertEquals(expectedResult, result)
    }
}
```

Estou usando *runBlocking* pois esse método é assícrono.

Como podem ver estou tentando mockar a minha classe porém o retorno dela é *null*, estou usando a biblioteca Mockito junto do JUnit para Kotlin descritos logo abaixo:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

A versão do meu Kotlin é **1.3.41** .

Answer (score 0):

Depois de conversar com devs mais experientes eu acabei adotando uma outra biblioteca chamada [MockK](https://mockk.io/) que é capaz de realizar o mock de interfaces e classes mais facilmente!

Comment: Hà uma alternativa ainda se estiveres a usar Spring. Chama-se springmockk da Ninja-squad. Eu uso isto em vários projectos que tenho no GitHub. Podes encontrar mais informação aqui: https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/springmockk